# InstanceID.GetToken returns incorrect token after Android app update

Tags: android, xamarin, notifications, push

I have an app that receives notifications just fine when you install it.  After its been updated one or more times it can no longer be notified.  Once the app is updated, it continues to re-issue the same token I got when the app was first installed, BUT when I check error message from GCM REST API it says "NotRegistered" at that point.

This is a Xamarin Native Android app.

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is this behavior happening with a released app, or is this a debug build?

Comment: This is a debug build

Comment: Thought so. Hope the code in answer is helpful to you. Seems like same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this same behavior in a Xamarin Forms app, but since the notification registration process is platform-specific, this might help in your case too.

In the Xamarin Droid service class that registers for notifications `OnHandleIntent` method, we delete the prior GCM instance id and request a new one on every run for debug builds:

```
    protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.Info("NotificationRegistrationIntentService", "Calling InstanceID.GetToken");
            lock (Locker)
            {
                var instanceId = InstanceID.GetInstance(this);
#if DEBUG
                // Ensure a fresh instance id for debug builds.
                instanceId.DeleteInstanceID();
                instanceId = InstanceID.GetInstance(this);
#endif
                var token = instanceId.GetToken(SenderId, GoogleCloudMessaging.InstanceIdScope, null);
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, this is very interesting!  I'm going to try this out.